# Overwriting a page title with Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've looked around for how to do this, but nothing is working.

I have a .phtml file and want to use this to overwrite the current title (which sits between the `<title></title>` tags).

I found somewhere that `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle("New Title");` was suppose to do it, but that doesn't. However `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();` correctly return the current title correctly.

Any help will be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in the *.phtml*. I would use the *local.xml* file and follow [this guide](http://inchoo.net/magento/change-any-page-title-in-magento/).

This allows you to set the title for different pages like so:

```xml
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setForcedTitle"><title>Account Dashboard</title></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: The thing is that I've got a static page called "offers" and I've hand coded this so that I can paginate through the pages, I want to append the page number to the title. So I can't really do this using XML. Or can i?

Comment: FYI, you are missing a closing `</action>`

Comment: Thank you! I used this method to override the homepage titles so that the titles would not also be appended with the store name (causing it to show twice).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it in the .phtml, easy solution here

you have set page tile like "Send email to friend" so open your sendfriend.xml file and set below code.

```
 <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="sendfriend"><title>Email to a Friend</title></action>
    </reference>
```

it's working..

Comment: I noticed your method is "setTitle" where as the accepted answer users "setForcedTitle" ... What is the difference?

Comment: It depends, If setTitle doesn't work then accepted solution must help, but you need to read inchoo article and make changes in head.php also.

Answer (score 0):

Magento loads head.phtml first.
So we cant override the title from another template file.

I had a similar requirement. What i did was below.

```
<title>
<?php
/*****************Customized For Title***********************/
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //Check With url
        $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $url = explode('/',$url);
        $url_key = $url[2]; //Set The url-key           

        $cateUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection ()
        ->addAttributeToSelect ('id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter ('url_key',  $url_key) //load the  category
        ->getFirstItem (); //only 1 result ; 

        $catSel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cateUrl->entity_id)->getMetaTitle();            

        //If Page title then Update
        if(!empty($catSel))
                 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($catSel);

        /*****************Customized For Title***********************/
        echo $this->getTitle() 
?>
</title>
```

In my case i needed to check the url and if the URL has a pagetitle from category it will overwrite it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this simply, by editing the page title in the "CMS" configuration in the admin panel. It's extremely simple, no need for any coding.